# How to send http request from https page? Can CORS solve this?

Tags: http, https, websocket

I have a website loaded with https, and I want to connect with my local server using http/websocket. Is it possible to establish connection with http/ws rather than https/wss? I know CORS but it seems not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found a workaround. Since SOP is just a browser behavior, while using extension, we can declare permissions and bypass this mechanism, it is rational and useful.

We can establish connection between https site with local server using http/websocket in extension.